# Content Search Webpart Help!

Tags: custom-list, managed-property, content-search-web-part

I would like to show a "News Article" list on my site collection homepage that queries customs lists on all sub sites and shows those that have a column yes/no value set to Yes.  How can this be achieved with a Content Search Web Part?

I tried to add a managed property but I couldn't get it to work correctly and so I need some advice now. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a search managed property against Yes/No column name.

Then update the content search web part 'query text' to filter the results by newly created search managed property.

```
Ex: ManagedProperty="Yes"
```

Hence the content search web part understands that it should pull only the results where the query matches.

Comment: I have the same problem and with me it does not work. When you build the string with the builder the YES is not within quotes, does it matter? I have tried all combinations, including contains etc, it does not work